# How to commit using Git without touching a folder

Tags: git, github

I have a project which contains many folder. But I want to commit all the folder except one lets suppose the name is `photo`.

How can I commit the whole project without touching this folder using `GIT`

Comment: add the folder in .gitignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the folder to `.gitignore` is what you should do, if you never want to commit this folder.

However, if you want to ignore the folder temporary, the solution is to stage (*prepare to commit*) everything, and then unstage the mentioned folder:

```
git add .
git reset path/to/directory
```

This way you can craft a commit without this folder and add the folder in a separate commit.

Answer (score 1):

there is a wonderful solution: `.gitignore` https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Answer (score 1):

add a `.gitignore` file in the main git folder

then add the require files and folders in the file .gitignore

for ex

```
*.py[cod]
*~
/photo
```

`*~` means  all files end with `~`

now `git add .gitignore`

then if you look `git status` you can't see the folder and files mentioned in gitignore file

now you can commit changes

`git commit -m "added git ignore"`

---

**Note:** git will not ignore files that was already tracked before a rule was added to this file to ignore it. In such a case the files must be un-tracked, in this case `git rm -r --cached photo/`